# Downgrading 3.7 to 3.6 verification error

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-3.6

I'm downgrading from 3.7 to 3.6 and receiving a verification error. I tried downgrading using `conda install python=3.6`. The `CondaVerificationError` pops up, which states:

> The package for scipy located at
>   C:\Users\Sailalitha\Anaconda3\pkgs\scipy-1.2.1-py36h29ff71c_0 appears
>   to be corrupted. The path
>   'Lib/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cp36-win_amd64.pyd' specified
>   in the package manifest cannot be found.

I checked the folder and the files seem to not be there. Please let me now how I can downgrade since I need to work on tensorflow for a project.

Windows 10 and Anaconda 3 are the machine specifications.

Comment: This is Solved. Thank you

Comment: This question will likely be useful to future visitors. If you've solved your problem, we would encourage you to post a self-answer to this question so anyone else who views the question will know how to solve it.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `keras`, or `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Sorry for the spam. I had deleted the scipy library and did not follow any tutorial. I had simply typed conda install keras and it did everything for me.